# Custom alert boxes NOT jquery where?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, user-interface, custom-controls, alert

I have tried to find some custom alert boxes , which don't use some libs like: jQuery, Prototype etc.. I want to get plain sample, which has rich UI as jQuery but doesn't use it.

I have tried to google, but have found an army of jQuery samples... I don't need it. Maybe you have links on websites with the plain js samples, which don't use some libs?

Because I want to get plain samples with rich UI, which are not based on libs like: jQuery, Prototype.js, Enyo etc

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think these links wil help you:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28812/Custom-Alert-Boxes-using-JavaScript-and-the-DOM
2. http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/customize-the-default-alert-function-of-javascript/

3.http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/04/custom-javascript-dialog-boxes/

Comment: by custom box I've meant not the simple alert, don't show that you are not understanding what I really need, it was also in the topic's body, there was meant plain js sample with rich UI, which doesn't use jQuery, prototype etc

Answer (score 2):

It's not very difficult. Basically all you've got to do is append both something to cover the whole screen and something to show the content to the body and position them correctly and attach event listeners to the right elements to remove it at the right time. All (well, most) of the positioning and styling can be done with CSS. For example, to position the thing to cover the whole screen, you could use this CSS:

```
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

You might even want to make it a little translucent so it's easier to tell that the dialog is modal:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```

[Try out a little example.](http://jsfiddle.net/LwvQT/embedded/result,js,css/)

Comment: so simple yet so perfect! awesome answer even in 2013.